# How to Post all the values

Tags: php

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                       $a=$row['diagnosis'];
                       $b=$row['icd_code'];

 echo' <div class="form-group"><div class="col-lg-8">  
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="disease" value="'.$a.'">'; 

echo '</div>
<div class="col-md-11 pull-right mrgT10">
<input type="text" class="tags" name="icd" value="';echo $b.'" />
</div>
</div>';    } ?>
```

This is my php coding.When i process the form using anotherpage php with the following code

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    echo $disease=$_POST['disease'].'<br/>';
    echo $icd=$_POST['icd'];    
}?>
```

It will get only the last value like this.

```
MONOPLEGIA
447637006
```

Is there anyway to get all the values.Any suggestion or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: `$a=$row['diagnosis'];` — `$a` is being overwritten on each loop iteration. It would only retain the value from the very last iteration. If you'd like to store the values in an array instead, use `$a[] = $row['diagnosis'];` instead.

Comment: What does `print_r($_POST)` show on your `anotherpage.php` ?

Comment: How can you expect different values if you are using same name for all

Comment: You should use `htmlspecialchars()` when you output variables in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it your textfields name as `name="disease[]"` , `name="icd[]"`  instead of `name="disease"` and `name="icd[]"`

and you can retrive like

```
$diseases=$_POST['disease'];

foreach($diseases as $key=>$disease){
     echo $disease;
     echo $icd=$_POST['icd'][$key];    
}
```

Also, change this `value="';echo $b.'"`  into `value="'.$b.'"`

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                       $a=$row['diagnosis'];
                       $b=$row['icd_code'];

 echo' <div class="form-group"><div class="col-lg-8">  
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="disease[]" value="'.$a.'">'; 

echo '</div>
<div class="col-md-11 pull-right mrgT10">
<input type="text" class="tags" name="icd[]" value="';echo $b.'" />
</div>
</div>';    } ?>
```

and call the value at other php :

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    foreach($_POST['disease'] as $a=>$key){
echo $disease=$a[$key].'<br/>';
    echo $icd=$_POST['icd'][$key]; 
}

}?>
```

hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass array so that you will get all values of result and serialize it and submit it to another form.
on next page you need to unserialize the array and you will get the whole array.
please try this code

```
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
         $a[] = $row[3];
             $b[] = $row[4];
        }
$var1 = serialize($a);
$var2 = serialize($b);
?>

**another_page.php**
<?php
print_r($_REQUEST);
$var1 =  unserialize($_POST['b']);
print_r($var1); 
die();
```

Hope U will get some thing...